# PHP stat(): узнать, является ли inode файлом или директорией

Tags: php, streamwrapper

Приветствую.

Пишу wrapper для своей схемы обращения к виртуальной файловой системе.

Наткнулся на обработку информации о файле. На странице [streamwrapper.url-stat](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/streamwrapper.url-stat.php) сказано, что именно этот метод вызывается при вызове `is_file` и `is_dir`. Типа, при вызове этих функций будет получаться `stat`, и на основании этих результатов будет возвращен тип inode. Вот только не ясно, что именно мне нужно возвращать в `stat`. Стандартная ф-ция `stat` возвращает массив:

```
'dev' => int 25            // номер устройства
'ino' => int 0             // номер inode *
'mode' => int 33206        // режим защиты inode
'nlink' => int 1           // количество ссылок
'uid' => int 0             // userid владельца *
'gid' => int 0             // groupid владельца *
'rdev' => int 25           // тип устройства, если устройство inode
'size' => int 3904         // размер в байтах
'atime' => int 1366318800  // время последнего доступа
'mtime' => int 1366398062  // время последней модификации
'ctime' => int 1366369846  // время последнего изменения inode
'blksize' => int -1        // размер блока ввода-вывода файловой системы **
'blocks' => int -1         // количество используемых 512-байтных блоков **
```

** В Windows это всегда будет 0.*

*** Доступен только на системах, поддерживающих тип st_blksize - другие системы (например, Windows) вернут -1.*

Если `stat` возвращает `false`, значит inode вообще не найден. Поэтому ф-ция `file_exists` обрабатывается нормально. А вот с `is_file` и `is_dir` не получается, всегда возвращает `false`:

```
$filepath = 'myscheme://some-file.ext';
var_dump(file_exists($filepath)); // true
var_dump(is_file($filepath));     // false
var_dump(is_dir($filepath));      // false
```

Отсюда вопрос: как по [stat()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.stat.php) определить, директория это или файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ага, оказалось, дело в `mode` — который «режим защиты inode».

Как сказано в [одном из комментариев](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php#51855), об этом в мануале не написано, до этого следовало дойти логически. Подумывал-было, но увидев дико странное число `33206` вместо привычного "0666", забыл об этом думать. Ну да, оно же тут в десятичной СИ, а права доступа нужно указывать в 8-й.

Итак, для файлов нужно указывать:

```
'mode' => octdec('0100666')  // или просто 0100666
```

а для директорий:

```
'mode' => octdec('040777')
```

Последние три числа (`666` и `777`) — это уже как будет необходимо (доступ владельцу, группе, гостю), а вот `0100` и `040`, стало быть, определяют тип inode.